# Написать php скрипт, который выводит массив виде списка. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Tags: php

[image: Как должен выглядеть массив в виде списка]

```
**Пытался следующим образом:**

*1-й способ:*
    function lite_list_array($array){
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($array as $value){
        echo '<li>';
        echo $value.' '.'<br>';
        echo '</li>';
    if(is_array($value)){
        echo '<ol>';
        foreach($value as $value2){
            echo '<li>';
            echo $value2.' '.'<br>';
            echo '</li>';
    if(is_array($value2)){
        echo '<ol>';
        foreach($value2 as $value3){
            echo '<li>';
            echo $value3.' '.'<br>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ol>';
        }        
    }
        echo '</ol>';
    }
}
    echo '</ol>';
}

*2-й способ:*
    function list_array($array) {
            echo "<ol>";
                foreach ($array as $value){
                    echo "<li>";
                if (is_array($value)){
                    list_array($value);
            } else {
                echo $value;
            }
            echo "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ol>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не пробовали просто при обходе обычного массива foreach делать проверку через if на то, что содержится в переменной которую сейчас обрабатывает foreach в текущем цикле?Например если строка, то делать $url."";, а если там массив, то делаеть обработку встроенным циклом foreach.Например:

```
$arr = array('a','b','c',array('d','e','f','g'),'h','j',array('k',array('l','q')),'w');
$cycle = 0;
foreach ($arr as $bolt){
        if(is_array($bolt) === true){
                    foreach($bolt as $param){
                            if(is_array($param) === true){
                            foreach($param as $pris){
                                    echo '____'.$cycle.'. '.$pris."</br>";
                                    }}
                                    else{                   
                                        echo '__'.$cycle.'. '.$param."</br>";}
            }
            }else {
            echo $cycle.'. '.$bolt."</br>";
            $cycle++;
            }
    }
```

Как-то так можно попробывать.Само собой переменную перечисления можно заменить на массив букв и потом просто делать для каждого пункта выборку нового последующего элемента с преращением на единицу элемента в конце текущей иттерации.

Comment: немного доработал код, чтобы работал корректно с вложенным массивом после k.Единственное что вам надо - это сделать список вместо двойных нижних подчеркиваний.